# Strange alignment of numbered headings

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, text-formatting

I am working on a word 2016 (actually 365) document that uses headings from the default styles.

I wanted to number the headings so that I could add cross-references. Following the [MS Office support article](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/Number-your-headings-ce24e028-4cb4-4d4a-bf25-fb2c61fc6585?ui=en-US&rs=en-IE&ad=IE) everything seemed to work fine, except I realised that some of my headings used the worng level (e.g. they are Heading 4 when they should be Heading 3, etc). So I set about correcting them.

Now it seems that when I have a numbered heading whose final number section reaches double digits the heading itself jumps out across the page by about a tab's (8 spaces) width. This is undesirable but I have not found out how to change whatever setting causes this.

```
12.2.9 Foo Title aligned Normally
Some normal text for about foo

12.2.10        Bar Title Aligned All The Way Over Here, WTF?
Some normal text about bar (Hmm the bar... damn it's only Tuesday!)
```

I am not able to place the cursor anywhere in this added space, just as with the numbers. But I can cause the *all* numbers and spacing to become highlighted in grey so it does appear that the spacing is part of the numbering style. How can I cahnge this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have spent another few mins looking! I again selected the multi-level list drop down from the Paragraph group, then `Define New Multilevel List`. near the bottom I selected `More`, then changed Follow number with from `Tab character` to `Space`.